# Use model in c# without a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I am relatively new to c# and ASP.NET MVC 5, but I was hoping for some help. I have an application where I have a class with about 20 variables. It has some `Guid`, some `List<string>`, `int`, `string`, etc. relatively simple. My controller will be passed this class, and then I need to send the data from the class down to the view, and then get it back to the controller on a form submit. Everywhere I see tutorials on how to use a model with entity framework, but nowhere have I found anything on just using a model without a database. Is it possible, (and if so, how)  to use model without a database? If it is not possible, what other ways could I go about using this? I thought about a session variable, but that seemed like a lot of overhead per user, i'm kind of stumped here. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't want all the overhead and extra code in my project, I just want a simple way to get a fair amount of data to and from my views/controllers

Comment: You don't need to moq anything, in fact your view models should be split apart from your domain models anyway... I'll post an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you use models in MVC...

**The Controller**

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        TestViewModel model = new TestViewModel
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Name = "Foo bar"
        };

        return this.View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Test(TestViewModel model)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.View(model);
        }

        return this.Content("Success");
    }
}
```

**The View Model**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**The View**

```
@model TestViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (this.Html.BeginForm())
{
    @(this.Html.ValidationSummary(false))
    @(this.Html.AntiForgeryToken())

    @(this.Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id))
    @(this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id))

    @(this.Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name))
    @(this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name))

    <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
}
```

Also by default MVC generates your routing table based on a simple naming convention, in this instance,navigate to `http://yoursite/example/test` to see this example in action

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a database to have models. Models just define the data to pass back and forth, so a database is definitely not necessary. In fact, the model should ideally be database agnostic. For instance, you might have a CustomerOrder model and Product model.

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Product> Products {get; set;}
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

You probably will need some sort of data storage (flat files, relational database, non-relational database, web based storage) but depending on the data you want to pass, it came from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

mvc models are pure c# objects to cary your information between controller and view. So you  can use them independent from data base. 
If you later need your information be persist  you can use EntityFramework code first or serialize them in a flat file.